# C++ Exceptions not allowed

Tags: qt, c++11, exception, gcc

Are there any reasons not to use C++ Exceptions with gcc?

Our company disallows them, but did not provide the reasoning behind the decision. Nobody of us "stupid people" can think of any reason why. Suggestions?

Comment: Without knowing precisely what kind of software you're developing, it's hard to say.  It does sound overly dogmatic though.  Perhaps time for a change of job?

Comment: Since you tagged this with [tag:qt], it may relate to Qt not relying on exceptions and simply following suit.

Comment: Thanks for the many answers. The applications are normal desktop applications nether critical nor realtime.

Answer (score 4):

Just guessing some reasons:

- Many rules are quite old and have been defined under assumptions / conditions that don't hold anymore. Early exception implementations had severe performance drawbacks, e.g. some compilers disabled optimizations completely. This is outdated and today exceptions are zero-overhead when not thrown. Throwing than has to do some work and thus is not free. Unfortunately, it is often very time-consuming to change the rules as they are part of some QA process.
- Embedded programmers often disallow exceptions. First, exceptions impose some size overhead for RTTI, which is also often banned in embedded code. Second, exceptions make it hard to reason about real-time performance because the performance is hard to predict.
- Exceptions require heap allocations. There are legitimate reasons to not allow this, e.g. safety, predictability in real-time environments or sometimes performance where you do not want heap allocations in the critical path
- Google's coding style has a no exception rule. The argument here is that the old code is not exception-safe, e.g. no RAII classes. If you introduce exceptions in such legacy code, it is likely that something breaks. However, I would strongly argue that the old code should be fixed instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are some pretty large application areas where exceptions commonly are forbidden. Embedded systems, console games, rarely use exceptions, because the platform may have limited or no support.

Bjarne Stroustrup helped write the JSF air vehicle coding standards, which also prohibit C++ exceptions.

http://www.stroustrup.com/JSF-AV-rules.pdf

The reasons are that in a situation where speed of response is life-critical, exceptions potentially slow down the code enough that it is an unreasonable risk to use them. Or, make it much harder to reason about the speed of the code.

Answer (score 0):

C++ exception implementation has the following drawbacks: prone to memory leaks, lack of callstack, crash when throw happens in a destructor, complexity of "noexcept".
It is very easy to create memory leaks when exceptions are adopted in a project. Since you don't know which method will throw, you must be very scrupulous when it comes to memory management and adapt all your codebase. This is why I use exceptions in C#, Java and Python projects but not in C++.  ​

Many C++ libs and frameworks don't use exceptions either (ex Qt)

Comment: I really recommend to lookup RAII and rule of zero / five if you have problems with memory management and exceptions. If you have to catch exceptions and manually `delete` objects you are doing something wrong.